# Picking out a string from varchar MySQL, Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, split, procedure, cut

Currently i am looking for a solution to "cut out a string" of a varchar.

I've a cursor which runs through all rows i get from a SQL Statement.
In each of those rows is a '#' included and this one i want to cut out and insert into another table.

But how can I cut the '#' and the characters following out?
I thought about splitting but found no solution how to do this in MySQL.

I hope you can help me

Comment: You could use the string functions, but the logic would be somewhat complex.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had a string like `first #second third`, you could use MySQL's string functions to extract `second`:

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(col, INSTR(col, '#') + 1),
          1,
          INSTR(SUBSTRING(col, INSTR(col, '#') + 1), ' ') - 1)
```

This assumes that there is only one hash sign (`#`), and that the delimeter for the end of the string you want to extract is a space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when there are more hashtags in one row? How can I handle this?

Comment: Well can you even describe the logic how you would determine _which_ hashtag is the one you want?  I would say that if it seems too complex, you might be better reading the data into your app layer and extracting it there.

Comment: No i don't want "the one" when there a more hashtags in this varchar i want to cut all out. After this i will add them in a new table.

Comment: How do you propose to do this?  One record might have 3 hashtags, another just one.  Would each hashtag be given a separate record?  Or, would you have one column for each hashtag?  MySQL isn't really the best tool to be using for this IMO.

Comment: I thought about a function or procedure with a varchar parameter. This function should split the whole varchar and after it should add the rows (from the splitted array) into an array and return this one.  Hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes, you could use a user defined function, but you still need to decide on how to store each hashtag.

Comment: The storing should be easy enough ^^ i will store each hashtag in a new table if you mean this "storing" otherwise is there any sort of array existing in SQL which I can loop over?

Answer (score 0):

Here's and example of a function to do this

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `cut`(`instring` varchar(255))
    RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET latin1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
begin
declare   tempstring varchar(100);
declare   outstring  varchar(100);
declare  checkit int;
declare  firsthashpos int; 
declare  tempid int;

set tempstring = ltrim(rtrim(instring));
set checkit = 0;


if instr(tempstring,'#') then set firsthashpos = instr(tempstring,'#'); end if; 

looper: while   tempstring is not null and instr(tempstring,'#') > 0 do

        set outstring = reverse(substring(reverse(tempstring),1,instr(reverse(tempstring),'#')));
        set tempstring = replace(tempstring,reverse(substring(reverse(tempstring),1,instr(reverse(tempstring),'#'))),'');

        insert into b (address) values (outstring);

end while; 

return concat(tempstring);
end//
delimiter ;
```

given this

```
select * from a;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | address             |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 13 #ont 12#45 st    |
|    2 | 13 #ont 12345 st    |
|    3 | 13 #ont 12#45 45678 |
|    4 | 56789 #ont 12#45 st |
+------+---------------------+
```

the result from

```
select id,address,cut(address)
from    a
where instr(address,'#') > 0;
```

Results in b

```
select * from b;
+----+---------------+
| id | address       |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | #45 st        |
|  2 | #ont 12       |
|  3 | #ont 12345 st |
|  4 | #45 45678     |
|  5 | #ont 12       |
|  6 | #45 st        |
|  7 | #ont 12       |
+----+---------------+
```

The return value from the function(outstring) contains what is left after the bits after the #s are removed. Hopefully the string manipulation in the function is self-explanatory.

Comment: Haha thanks, but i decided to do this stuff in php :)